# click and run one function of two different function in one div in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I create two div and each div had different angular function. I want click one of them using ng-click. if one of div get a click, hope me it will running their own function but in my case it always run both of function. this my code looks like :

this is my html code :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div ng-click="titi();" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:red;">
         <div ng-click="toto();" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:yellow;">Click me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my angular code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function Ctrl1($scope) {

    $scope.toto = function(){
        alert('toto');
    };

    $scope.titi = function(){
        alert('titi');
    };
}
```

if I click yellow div, it show alert toto and titi. And if I click red div, it show alert just titi. All I want is when I click one of them, they will run their own function click. is there something wrong? please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here click on the inner element div is propagated to the outer div. Use `$event.stopPropagation();` prevent click propagation:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div ng-click="titi();" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:red;">
         <div ng-click="toto(); $event.stopPropagation();" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:yellow;">Click me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your DOM tree events are bubbling, in order to prevent it use

```
ng-click="toto(); $event.stopPropagation();"
```

You can read details further :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation